# Combine two sprites into prefab Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I have two sprites I downloaded off the asset store on my canvas one is a building, one is the foundation the building sits on.

[image]

However, in my game these two sprites will always be together. I'm going to be creating many instances of these on my map and I don't want to have to drag each piece on to the map individually and position them. So I was hoping to highlight them both and turn them into a prefab so Id just have to manage one object instead of dragging around both sprites.

I could just open them in photoshop and combine the two images but I'd prefer to just put them together in unity and leave my sprites modular.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you'd like to do with them in a prefab? If I were you, I would have a sprites folder and then I would just put these 2 in a subfolder together.

Comment: @XanderLuciano I edited the question some to hopefully make it more clear. Basically I'm going to be creating many instances of these sprites on my map, so instead of having to drag the top piece out and then the bottom piece out and position them together for each instance, I'd rather have a prefab of them combined that I could just drag onto my canvas and be done.

Comment: It would be better for performance and easier for you if you combined them

Comment: You could parent them under a container GameObject, then make that a prefab I guess?

Comment: @Serlite would the new GameObject prefab be treated (performance wise) like 1 game object or 3? If 3 then I think I'll just combine the sprites like Xander said. I was just hoping to be able to switch the "tops" easier than opening photoshop

Comment: Performance-wise, it would technically be better to have a single sprite rather than two sprites grouped under a GameObject (as the engine will have to keep track of the parent transform and the two child transforms now). However, the actual impact will be negligible (unless you scale up the situation tremendously) - in the end, just do what makes sense. If the sprites will never ever be used separately, then it's logical to make them a single asset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a empty object. This object is parent object.
Then in hierarchy window, you drag 2 sprite to this parent object. So 2 sprites is child of parent object. Make this parent object as prefab.